# update list of objects without copy it Flutter Bloc

Tags: flutter, list, dart, bloc, state-management

I'm new with using flutter bloc state management and Equatable package , when I need to update List in the bloc file I have to make a copy for every single element in the list to successfully emit new list even if I need to change or add only 1 element!
Like the example bellow..

```
class Message extends Equatable {
  Message({
    required this.id,
    required this.content,
  });

  final String id;
  final String content;

         Message copyWith({
            String? id,
            String? content,
          }) {
            return Message(
              id: id ?? this.id,
              content: content ?? this.content,
            );
          }
        
          @override
          // TODO: implement props
          List<Object?> get props => [
                id,
                content,
              ];
        }
    
    //bloc file
         Futurer<void> _onUpdateMessagesMessageEvent(
              UpdateMessagesMessageEvent event, Emitter<Bloctate> emit) async {
            String messageId = Uuid().v4();
           List<Message> messages = List.generate(state.messages.length, (index) =>state.messages[index].copyWith());
            messages.add(Message(
                    id: messageId,
                    content: event.textEditingController.text,
                   ));
        
            emit(BlocState(messages: messages));
        
          }
    
    //state file
        class BlocState extends Equatable {
          List<Message> messages;
          BlocState({
            required this.messages,
            });
          @override
          List<Object> get props => [
                messages,];
        }
```

I need to update 'messages' list and add 1 element to it without being forced to copy all elements in the list

Answer (score 2):

Bloc States should be immutable meaning you have to copy the existing `List` add new `Message` to the copied `List` and emit a new state.

```
  void _onUpdate(UpdateMessage event, Emitter<MessageState> emit) {
    final id = const Uuid().v4();
    emit(MessageState(
        messages: List.of(state.messages)..add(Message(id, event.content))));
  }
```